# Excel finding a cell based on a value in an adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to find the contents of a specific cell

My particular problem is that I have multiple columns with different dates as the heading, and then reading down that column I have multiple blanks.  When a specific occurrence of a number from 1 to 10 appears, I want to be able to return the content of the adjacent cell in the next column.

For example, if today is 27th March, which matches the date in one of my columns, then searching down the column, after several blank cells there is the number 1 and in the adjacent cell is the time 23:00.

I want to search the column of the date for the numbers and then return the contents of the time in the cell adjacent to the number.

[image: Example 2 with descriptions]

Comment: show us some sample data, this sounds like a VLOOKUP will do the trick

Comment: Mon 26
COAL43185 BIOMASS43185 COAL
  
 1 
  
1  23:09
  
 2 
  
  
  
  
2  01:55
  
 3 
  
3  03:00
  
  
I don't know if the above is very clear, but referencing the date at the top, I need to search down the columns until I find 1 and then return the 23:09 as shown

Comment: Sorry the format on that wasn't great, at the top of column B is a date which is referenced from a different sheet, reading down column B the are several blank cells, then a 1 may appear, in the cells in column C are times, what I want to do, is reference the date, search down the column until I find the 1 and then return the contents in Cell C that shows the time

Comment: please don't provide new information in comments, but edit your question. You can format your data e.g. here: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Ive added a picture that shows the table

Comment: Your picture doesn't match your description, and your description is very confusing.  Please post a complete example, showing all of the relevant columns, the exact result you want, how you locate/select the starting cell, and use that example to explain exactly how you get the result.  Explain the relevance of blank cells and what to do about them.  If you can add a little context to help understand what we're looking at, that might help to understand the task.

Comment: Ive added another picture to try to show more clearly what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This formula will do what you want:

`=OFFSET(A1,MATCH(1,INDEX(A1:D31,,MATCH(TODAY(),A1:D1,0)),0)-1,MATCH(TODAY(),A1:D1,0))`

Note that the date you've shown as "Mon 26" must be a real date serial number, formatted as "ddd dd", or the comparison to `TODAY()` won't work correctly.  Also, I've assumed your data starts in `A1`.

If you want to search for other numbers in the column, you can replace the "1" in the first MATCH() with a different number or a cell reference.

**How it works:** The `INDEX()` returns a whole column (because the `row_num` parameter is omitted) specified by the second `MATCH()`, which finds today's date in the row of column headings.

That column is fed to the first `MATCH()`, which returns the position of the "1" in that column, and that position (minus 1) is used as the row offset in the `OFFSET()` function. Finally, the last `MATCH()` finds today's date again, and that is used for the column offset.